# Can I reuse a TCP connection?

Tags: c++, windows, http, networking, tcp

I'm connecting to a website and retrieving HTTP data by sending it a GET request. And I have to connect to the same site twice to retrieve two different pages. I'm new to network programming but I believe the `connect` function connects to the server, and creates a tcp connection.

Now each time I connect to the server to retrieve the HTTP data, it has to create a new tcp connection, is there any way I can reuse the old one? It's retrieving the http data immediately after the other.
It's not that big of a deal but I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `HTTP 1.1` where connection are [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) or use HTTP 1.0 and send the header "Connection: Keep-Alive".

That way you can fetch a second page without connecting again (just `GET` again on the same socket).

Comment: Do I have to send the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header on the before and after packets? Or just the first one to keep that one alive long enough for the second one?

Comment: @Josh Send it the way you send the other headers, at the beginning of the request.

Comment: If i'm using `HTTP 1.1` do I still need to send `Connection: Keep-Alive`?

Comment: @Josh No, it's implicit for HTTP 1.1

Comment: Alright, last question. Can I send the 2nd `GET` request if i'm in the middle of receiving from the first one?

Comment: @Josh Not sure about that one but I don't think it could work. Check the RFC to make sure and let me know.

Comment: @Josh: Yes, it's called [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining). You may send both rqeuests at the same time even.